# CiviCase - Having issues

Tags: civicase

[image]

When trying to add a record in case, I get the above screen.

I was originally having an issue with editing Case Types. Even trying to enable or disable wasn't working. Since updating to 4.7.3 the enable and disable seems to be working.

This is running on Joomla v3.4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you seem to have deleted the "case coordinator" relationship type, yet one or more of your case types depends on it. Either restore that relationship type, or remove it from the case type configuration.